# How to use the Discord JS Client without logging in?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I have a service that listens for certain updates and then uses a Discord Bot to post a message on a channel. A random example: every time a team scores a goal, post a message in a channel. I got an email from Discord to reset my bot token because there were too many logins.

As you know, in order to use the Bot you use the `client.login("XXX")` method. So every time there is an update my service initializes the bot and then sends a message. My assumption is that it has to do with me calling `client.login("XXX")` for every update. Since my service runs serverless, I can not keep the service up.

Is there a way to make the bot post a message without having to use `client.login("XXX")`? Or can anyone suggest any strategy to make this logic work?

Comment: What's wrong with calling `client.login("XXX")` every time?

Comment: Sounds like you should be using a webhook instead of a bot

Comment: @Konrad the message said "The bot connected to Discord more than X times within a short time period". So it seems the problem is the frequency. So I'm trying to think how to do it without the client.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible as a bot cannot do any actions without being logged in, it sounds like channel webhooks would fit your needs better.

You simply generate a webhook link in a channel which you can then post messages to through a post request.

You can read more about webhooks [here](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/228383668-Intro-to-Webhooks)

And you can read more about the required paramters and how to format a POST request to the webhook [here](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/webhook#:%7E:text=Webhooks%20are%20a%20low%2Deffort,user%20or%20authentication%20to%20use.)